VU allocation for K6s
How do VUs get allocated in K6? Does it depend on the kind of machine on which you run the load tests? I am runnng K6 with a GH selfhosted runner. It's a GCP VM. In some cases I can see execptione like
" Error while allocating unplanned VU". Trying to understand if we need a VM with higher configuration.
Is there any documents available related to this?

https://github.com/grafana/k6/blob/913b280c9fb57a643842ea824f35299e568283f3/lib/executor/constant_arrival_rate.go#L298
